# Regex to validate only digits from 0-9, maximum of 8 digits till a dot and only two decimals as maximum

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I haven't used regular expressions at all, so I'm having difficulty troubleshooting. I'm looking for a regex that can help me to validate if there are only digits from 0-9,
only 8 digits till a dot and two decimals as maximum.

For example:

33445566.09

```
/[0-9]/
```

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Try: `/^[0-9]{8}\.[0-9]{1,2}$/`

Comment: If it is some live input validation (e.g. in React), you might need something like `/^[0-9]{1,8}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/`

Comment: By only 8 digits do you mean exactly 8 digits or up to 8 digits?

Answer (score 1):

```
/[0-9]{1,8}\.[0-9]{1,2}/
```

If you want to just match or not

`[0-9]` means match 0 or 1 or ... 9

`{1,8}` means it can match minimum 1 and maximum 8

`\.`    means escape .

If you want to get the group just use () in the regex

```
/([0-9]{1,8})\.([0-9]{1,2})/
```

This way you can get
`33445566` and `09`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String input = "123456789.12";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,8}\\.[0-9]{1,2}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches()); //false
```

- ^  start of line
- $  end of line
- [0-9] only 0123456789
- {1,8} symbols count from 1 to 8 include